# Simple XML to parse general recordset

Tags: php, xml, simplexml, recordset

I am trying to find a way to iterate through an XML recordset containing a namespace. However, I don't know the field names in advance. Sample XML is below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://www.site.com/SMART/Updates">
<NewDataSet>
    <record>
        <FIELD1>data1</FIELD1>
        <FIELD2>data2</FIELD2>
        <FIELD3>data3</FIELD3>
    </record>
    <record>
        <FIELD1>data1</FIELD1>
        <FIELD2>data2</FIELD2>
        <FIELD3>data3</FIELD3>
    </record>
</NewDataSet>
```

Again, I won't know the field names in advance. I need read the namespace, find the name of the root element ("NewDataSet", in this case) and then need to get the field names and values of the individual elements. I have tried to use $xml->getname(), and $xml->xpath('\') to find the root element name, but been unable to crack it.

Comment: I added the PHP tag - hopefully this is correct :-)

Comment: You have posted invalid XML in your question. No standard conform XML parser can be used to answer your question in a predictable manner unless you fix the input XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *[(as discussed in Chat)](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/5807949#5807949)*

[Plain DOM functions](http://php.net/book.dom) are the best way to process XML.

[**Demo**](http://codepad.org/0faT26Di) or **code:**

```php
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
$xml = <<<END
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://www.site.com/SMART/Updates">
<NewDataSet>
    <record>
        <FIELD1>data1</FIELD1>
        <FIELD2>data2</FIELD2>
        <FIELD3>data3</FIELD3>
    </record>
    <record>
        <FIELD1>data1</FIELD1>
        <FIELD2>data2</FIELD2>
        <FIELD3>data3</FIELD3>
    </record>
</NewDataSet>
</string>
END;
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->normalize();
$dom->loadXML($xml);
echo 'Root element name: ' . $dom->firstChild->firstChild->tagName . PHP_EOL;
echo 'Number of child elements: ' . count($dom->firstChild->firstChild->childNodes) . PHP_EOL;
echo '=====' . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
echo print_node($dom->firstChild->firstChild);
function print_node($node, $level = 0, $prev_level = 0) {
    $result = '';
    if($node->hasChildNodes()) {
        foreach($node->childNodes as $subnode) {
            $result .= str_repeat('    ', $level) . $node->tagName . ' =>' . PHP_EOL;
            $result .= print_node($subnode, $level + 1, $level) . PHP_EOL;
        }
    } else {
        if(trim($node->nodeValue) !== '') {
            $result .= str_repeat('    ', $level) . '**Data: ' . trim($node->nodeValue) . PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
?>
```

**Output:**

```
Root element name: NewDataSet
Number of child elements: 1
=====

NewDataSet =>
    record =>
        FIELD1 =>
            **Data: data1


    record =>
        FIELD2 =>
            **Data: data2


    record =>
        FIELD3 =>
            **Data: data3



NewDataSet =>
    record =>
        FIELD1 =>
            **Data: data1


    record =>
        FIELD2 =>
            **Data: data2


    record =>
        FIELD3 =>
            **Data: data3
```

Comment: Why use DOM rather than SimpleXML? As the name suggests, it is very simple to use, and entirely adequate for the questioner's needs.

Comment: @IMSoP When you need to do more advanced things with XML, you will end up having to switch to DOM anyway, and so it's better to *start* with DOM rather than have to rewrite the code later. See [this](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/11?m=5808465#5808465).

Comment: So far, I've never needed to use anything other than SimpleXML to interact with XML APIs. The only two things I know that it makes fundamentally difficult/impossible are navigating upwards, and editing, but DOM is hardly a user-friendly way of writing an entire XML document, so I'm happy with that. Plus, you can mix and match DOM and SimpleXML code easily, as "importing" from one to the other is a cheap operation (it just re-wraps the memory structure).

Comment: @IMSoP Everyone has their own preference, but this has solved their problem. [Read](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/11?m=5808257#5808257) [through](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/11?m=5808272#5808272) [the](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/11?m=5808350#5808350) [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/11?m=5808381#5808381) [messages](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/11?m=5808391#5808391).

Comment: I'm happy with personal preferences, but you described DOM as "the best way". I can't see anything on this page or the chat logs justifying the claim that SimpleXML is less suited to this task.

Comment: @IMSoP Perhaps [@DaveRandom's comment](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/11?m=5808465#5808465)?

Comment: I see no examples, only hyperbole ("abandon 95% of XML") and vague personal anecdote.

Comment: (Which, again, is fine. But my own experience of SimpleXML is the opposite: it has made simple all the things I wanted to do with it, including the kind of thing discussed in this question.)

Answer (score 0):

Your XML is invalid, but assuming the string tag is closed after the `</NewDataSet>` tag:

You can get the namespaces declared in the document using `getDocNamespaces()`.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlfile);
$namespaces = $xml->getDocNamespaces(); //array of namespaces

$dataset = $xml->children(); //first child (NewDataSet)

echo $dataset->getName(); //NewDataSet

$records = $dataset->children();
$i = 0;
$result = array();
foreach ($records as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($value as $fieldName => $fieldData) {
        $result[$i][$fieldName] = (string)$fieldData;
    }
    $i++;
}
var_dump($result);
```

Now `$result` contains an array that is easier to read and contains the rows :

```
array(2) {
  [0]=> array(3) {
            ["FIELD1"]=> string(5) "data1"
            ["FIELD2"]=> string(5) "data2"
            ["FIELD3"]=> string(5) "data3"
        }
  [1]=>  array(3) {
            ["FIELD1"]=> string(5) "data1"
            ["FIELD2"]=> string(5) "data2"
            ["FIELD3"]=> string(5) "data3"
        }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Something is not rights. When I try to print the name of the root node ("echo $dataset->getName();"), I get an empty string. I am using WAMP. I think I have turned any extensions that I may need. But still, no luck.

Comment: @DonBriggs The above works for me (as mentioned, your question is missing the `</string>` from the end of the XML). You could try using these debug functions to look at the SimpleXML object you're getting back at each stage: http://github.com/IMSoP/simplexml_debug

Answer (score 0):

I don't actually understand what you problem is, in your [said real-life XML you gave in PHP chat](http://sandbox.ijeannie.com/), there are no namespaces involved (and even if!).

Just read out the tag-name from the document element:

```
# echoes NewDataSet / string (depending on which XML input)
echo dom_import_simplexml($simplexml)->ownerDocument->documentElement->tagName;
```

---

If you have actually an XML document inside another XML document, you can do the following:

```
// load outer document
$docOuter = new DOMDocument();
$docOuter->loadXML($xmlString);

// load inner document
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($docOuter->documentElement->nodeValue);

echo "Root element is named: ", $doc->documentElement->tagName, "\n";
```

---

Or if you prefer SimpleXML:

```
echo "Root element is named: ",
      simplexml_load_string(simplexml_load_string($xmlString))->getName()
;
```

Comment: As I've asked on another answer, why switch to DOM rather than SimpleXML?

Comment: Internally SimpleXML and DOM use the same library, so this is not fully a switch. DOM has a more differentiated interface which I normally prefer, the *"Simple"* in SimpleXML could be read as *limited* as well. Btw. you can convert vice-versa (as the answer shows), so this is normally no problem. Maybe I was just lazy to search if SimpleXML has something comparable to the `documentElement` property of DOM.

Comment: Yes, I realise it's trivial processing-wise. But as is often the case, the limitation is in your understanding rather than the library: you don't need "documentElement", because that's the element you already have: `echo $simplexml->getName()` does the same thing in about a 10th of the keystrokes. SimpleXML is actually quite a powerful interface, but its looks are deceptive sometimes. :)

Comment: Yes that works but you need to have the right element here. If you have a different one (you didn't share any code), it's not that trivial. However in your case, you can just do it like you outlined it. I'm pretty sure you're able to "convert" the DOM code into something equivalent with SimpleXML.

Comment: Indeed, navigating upwards rather than downwards is the one thing SimpleXML doesn't make trivial. However, the question here was "given this string of XML, how do I find the name of the outermost tag", which requires no upwards navigation. In short, I prefer using simple functions for simple problems.

Comment: `simplexml_load_string(simplexml_load_string($xmlString))->getName();` its more or less a matter of taste.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [the chat transcript posted in another answer](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/5807949#5807949), it looks like the  element actually contains a string which is an **escaped** XML document. So there is exactly one element in the outer document, called `<string>`. It has no children, just content. (This looks remarkably like someone using ASP.net's service-builder.)

So the step you are missing is unescaping this inner XML to treat as a new XML document:

```
// Parse the outer XML, which is just one <string> node
$wrapper_sx = simplexml_load_string($wrapper_xml);
// Extract the actual XML inside it
$response_xml = (string)$wrapper_sx;
// Parse that
$response_sx = simplexml_load_string($response_xml);

// Now handle the XML
$tag_name = $response_sx->getName();
foreach ( $response_sx->children() as $child )
{
    // Etc
}

// see http://github.com/IMSoP/simplexml_debug
simplexml_tree($response_sx, true);
```